# Table: Fixed thead during scroll with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to fix the `thead` on [this table](http://ap.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/434-2/) when you scroll the table, but without any results.

This is the JS I tried:

```
<script>
   document.getElementById("tablepress-10").addEventListener("scroll", function() {
      var translate = "translate(0," + this.scrollTop + "px)";
      this.querySelector("thead").style.transform = translate;
   });
</script>
```

Any tips?

Comment: Tips: 1. Describe the problem, specifically.  What happens? Doesn't happen? 2. Open your developer console in your browser and look - are there any errors?  3. Set up a jsfiddle or similar (https://jsfiddle.net/) in order to provide an [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved mostly out of HTML/CSS, on a good bunch of browsers.

Here's a good round-up of solutions for tables with fixed headers, mostly CSS: [Scrolling HTML Table with Fixed Header](https://rcswebsolutions.wordpress.com/2007/01/02/scrolling-html-table-with-fixed-header/)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a plugin. I know of this one for using jQuery http://laertejjunior.github.io/freezeheader/#demo